# Dynamically load SWF file with Java

Tags: java, html

I want to load SWF file dynamically in my webpage. But I don't know how to do it. Is it possible to load SWF from back-end? In this website [Insert SWF into html page](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/2093) I found a way to load SWF, but it is static. I have a database where I will store the paths of the SWF files and load those files dynamically. Is there any way to dynamically change the source of the swf object [ "EMBED SRC="file.swf" ]?
Any information will be very helpful to me. Thank you.

Comment: Are you just hosting static html pages on their own or is there some actual Java involved here somewhere?

Comment: I guess you actually want to use JavaScript to do that. Using Java would probably be overkill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I have no personal experience using Wicket, but here's how I understood it should go. Use the [AttributeModifier](http://wicket.sourceforge.net/apidocs/wicket/AttributeModifier.html) to change the value of the `value` attribute of the `param` tag and the `src` attribute of the `movie` tag. You also need to give them the Wicket id's on the HTML template to be able to refer them from the Java code. In general the HTML template would look something like this:

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
  width="300" height="170"
  codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/swflash.cab">
  <param wicket:id="swfReference1" name="movie" value="" />
  <param name="quality" value="high" />
  <param name="bgcolor" value="#000000" />
  <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
  <embed wicket:id="swfReference2" src="" quality="high" bgcolor="#000000"
    width="300" height="170" align="middle"
    play="true"
    loop="false"
    allowScriptAccess="always"
    type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
    pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
  </embed>
</object>
...
```

You could also do it on JavaScript level to be even more dynamic by using for instance jQuery to switch the SWF sources. [Here's a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/hvhcA/1/).

```
$('param[name=movie]').attr('value', 'https://demo.adobe.com/Home.swf');
$('embed').attr('src', 'https://demo.adobe.com/Home.swf');
```

Comment: I am designing the webpage by Wicket. Is this supported in Wicket?

Comment: I guess the JavaScript example would work as is. I modified the Java example to take Wicket into account since it has its own templating system. Depending on your use-case, I'd also consider using just JavaScript to change the SWF and avoid the page load.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will try and let you know.